# Enum condition behavior : enum_Var = str1 Or str2

Tags: vba, excel

(I will use a simple example and not my original code, not relevant)

I wanted to make a `If` statement on an Enum, with `Or`. Excel VBA editor suggested to use this kind of syntax : `If current = Apple Or Peach Then`(Dropdown choice, see below)

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Well, curious but why not.
I figured out while testing that the behavior wasn't the one expect :

```
Public Enum Fruit
    Apple
    Peach
    Banana
End Enum

Public Sub pick()

    Dim current As Fruit
    current = Banana
    
    If current = Apple Or Peach Then
        '//The condition is True
        MsgBox "Toc"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Indeed, in this code, the `If` is True. Not that I don't know why : I think `Peach` is evaluated as an Integer or so, beeing different from 0, it's a `true`. Proof, if in the `Enum Fruit` declaration, `Peach` is forced to 0, it's a `False`.

```
Public Enum Fruit
    Apple
    Peach = 0
    Banana
End Enum

Public Sub pick()

    Dim current As Fruit
    current = Banana
    
    If current = Apple Or Peach Then
        '//The condition is False this time
        MsgBox "Toc"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

My question (yeah, not vital, for understanding) : why the hell would the editor suggest me this drop down list as in the above screenshot ? I feel like there is something hidden there...

**EDIT**
I am not looking for a way to write this condition (as it is quite obvious `If current = Apple Or current = Peach Then`). My question relates to the drop down list suggestion.

Comment: Write if condition as- "If current = Apple Or current = Peach Then"

Comment: @RamAnuragi Yeah, no problem for that, the "problem" is more about the editor behavior with the drop down list suggestion.

Comment: If the Enum's are setup up as bit-masks then you can AND and OR them together.  This was frequently done in larger VB6 app development, which is why the IDE is suggesting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because an ENUM is usually a representation of some integer constants and used for masking.

So in your example apple = 0, peach = 1, Banana = 2

With OR and AND you can combine those values, often used for bit masking.
With ur example values it wouldn't make much sense. Usually you would use bit values like 1, 2, 4, 8, 16.

And if you want to set an option for something you can say 1 OR 2, which would mask the first 2 bits (=3) which would represent both options should be used.

Comment: Thank you @Mono, I understand now the logic with the use of And/Or between Enum. I will keep that in mind, as it may be very usefull...

Answer (score 1):

If you set n^2 values in your Enum, it'll be very useful - and Or will also make sense then. My code probably makes more sense than my explanation:

```
Public Enum Fruit
    Apple = 1
    Peach = 2
    Banana = 4
End Enum

...

If (Apple Or Peach) ' The Or here is a binary Or. 1+2=3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !